# Trying to position plots next to each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to position two plots next to each other, but I don't know how do it right.

This is the first plot:

```
x_new = np.linspace(dsa[0], dsa[-1], num=len(dsa)*10)
coefs = poly.polyfit(dsa, Wechsel, 1)
ffit = poly.polyval(x_new, coefs)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Druck p in mbar")
plt.ylabel("Minimawechsel N")
plt.plot(x_new, ffit, color="red", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1)
plt.plot(dsa, Wechsel, 'ro', label="Sauerstoff")
plt.legend(loc=1)
```

This is the second one:

```
x_new1 = np.linspace(dar[0], dar[-1], num=len(dar)*10)
coefs1 = poly.polyfit(dar, Wechsel, 1)
ffit1 = poly.polyval(x_new1, coefs1)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Druck p in mbar")
plt.ylabel("Minimawechsel N")
plt.plot(x_new1, ffit1, color="blue", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1)
plt.plot(dar, Wechsel, 'ro', color='blue', label="Argon")
plt.legend(loc=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plt.subplots`:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

x_new = np.linspace(dsa[0], dsa[-1], num=len(dsa)*10)   
coefs = poly.polyfit(dsa, Wechsel, 1)
ffit = poly.polyval(x_new, coefs)
ax1.grid(True) 
ax1.set_xlabel("Druck p in mbar")                   
ax1.set_ylabel("Minimawechsel N")
ax1.plot(x_new, ffit, color="red", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1)
ax1.plot(dsa,Wechsel,'ro', label="Sauerstoff" )
ax1.legend(loc=1)
```

and similarly with ax2:

```
x_new1 = np.linspace(dar[0], dar[-1], num=len(dar)*10)   
coefs1 = poly.polyfit(dar, Wechsel, 1)
ffit1 = poly.polyval(x_new1, coefs1)
ax2.grid(True)                              
ax2.set_xlabel("Druck p in mbar")                   
ax2.set_ylabel("Minimawechsel N")
ax2.plot(x_new1, ffit1, color="blue", linestyle="solid", linewidth=1)
ax2.plot(dar,Wechsel, 'ro',color='blue', label="Argon")
ax2.legend(loc=1)
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.

It worked, but there is a problem with x axis.

I made a screenshoot of it: http://docdro.id/ytauVF0   .  
Its to tight, Is there a way to make it more wide?

Comment: @Heißenberg93 There are multiple ways to solve this problem. What I would do is customize the number of ticks on the x-axis using `ax.set_xticks()` (http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks). You'll need to calculate the ticks yourself though (I would start from the existing ticks using `ax1.get_xticks()`)

Comment: @JulienSpronck thank you for your post here. I am trying to use it on my code and I get AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt' for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: @mkheifetz I'm guessing somewhere you typed either `ax1.plt` or `ax2.plt`. `ax1` and `ax2` are of the `AxesSubplot` type and they do not have a `plt` attribute.